# Ajax with php classes

Tags: php, ajax, oop

I want to use AJAX to show a form when a user clicks on record to edit it.
I know and capable of using AJAX.

But now i want to call a method of a class in PHP. And thats where im stuck.

Below some code sample of my controller:

```
public function start() {

    $users = $this->usersmodel->getAllUsers();

    $firstRow = new HtmlTableFirstRow();

    $table = new HtmlTable($users,$users,$firstRow);

    $table->setCss('table1');

    echo $table->show();



}

public function editRecord() {

    $recordId = $this->getFirstParameter();

    $user = $this->usersmodel->getUserById($recordId);

    $tableId = $this->fieldModel->getTableIdByName('users');

    $inputs = $this->fieldModel->getFields($tableId);

    $collection = new Fieldcollection($inputs);

    foreach($collection as $inputs) {

        for($i = 0; $i < count($inputs); $i++) {

            foreach($user as $userInfo) {

                $inputs[$i]->setValue($userInfo[$i]);

            }

        }

    }

    $form = new Form($collection);

    $form->setLabels();

    $form->setCss('form1');

    echo $form->show();

}
```

As you can see i have 2 functions, start which shows all the records. And when a user clicks on editrecord a form will show.

I want to show the form in a popup, without a page refresh.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: You route the AJAX request the way you would route any other request using the url that will be matched to your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a page for manage ajax requests like this:

**server.php** :

```
    if(isset($_GET['request'])){
        switch($_GET['request']){
            case 'get-form' :
                $userId = $_GET['userId'];
                $form = new Form($collection);

                $form->setLabels();

                $form->setCss('form1');

                echo $form->show();
            break;
        }
}
```

in client page you can send ajax request & get their result via jquery :
**client.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr data-userId="1">
            <td>User 1</td>
            <td><button class="edit">Edit Record</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-userId="2">
            <td>User 2</td>
            <td><button class="edit">Edit Record</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-userId="3">
            <td>User 3</td>
            <td><button class="edit">Edit Record</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="popup">

    </div>
</body>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</html>
```

ajax.js :

```
    (function(){
    $('.popup').hide();
    $('.edit').on('click',function(){
        var userId = $(this).parent().parent().data('userId');
        $.get('server.php',{request : 'get-form' , userId : userId},function(form){
            $('.popup').empty().append(form).fadeIn();
        });
    });
})();
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. This helps me.
i can work with this!